# Can I remove build and devel folders

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just followed the doc to install ROS1 from source.

After the installation, I got three folders: `build_isolated devel_isolated install_isolated`, then I execute `source install_isolated/setup.bash`. Now the installation of ROS has been done.

My question is if I can remove `build_isolated` and `devel_isolated`?

The doc says:

> The build folder is where cmake and
> make are invoked, and the devel folder
> contains any generated files and
> targets, plus setup.*sh files so that
> you can use it like it is installed.

I'm not sure if I can remove them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287969/can-i-remove-build-and-devel-folders/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will depend:

- if you're going to add more packages to your "base ROS install", then keeping the `build` and `devel` folders around might reduce build times, as depending on what those new packages need, certain pkgs that are dependencies will need to be rebuilt.
- if you're not going to add any packages (that would be a rare situation, but can happen), or are going to create an [overlay workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) (recommended for source installs), then the `build` and `devel` (and their `_isolated` variants) can be removed. As long as the overlay workspace extends the `install` space of the underlay, of course.

Finally: a general tip for working with source installs: enable `ccache`. Even if you need to rebuild large parts of your base workspace, it'll be very fast, especially in cases where not a lot of files have been updated / changed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0